# Issue configuring Google Compute Engine VM ingress firewall rule

Tags: google-compute-engine, firewall

I have a small GCE VM setup w/ npm and a node.js app running on port 8080. I can do:

'''curl http://localhost:8080'''

and get the index page back so the server is running.

I have made the IP address static (not ephemeral).

Here are the filter rule settings:

[image]

However I cannot connect externally and it just says the site can't be reached and the server refused to connect. I turned on logging for the firewall rule but don't see any traffic there so puzzled what that could mean. I assume the traffic isn't even getting to the rule?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Edit your question and show your code that creates the server and sets up listen. Most likely your server is listening on `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` instead of all interfaces `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Hi John that was it. If you add that as an answer I'll confirm.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your node.js application is listening on `localhost`, or `127.0.0.1` (IPv4) or `[::1]` (IPv6). These addresses are assigned to the loopback interface which means that only connections from inside the computer are accepted.

The solution is to change your code to listen to all network interfaces. This is defined as the pseudo address `0.0.0.0`.

In the following example, notice the line that contains `listen(8080, "0.0.0.0");`. This defines what interface(s) the application is listening on for connections.

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8080, "0.0.0.0");
console.log('Server is running and listening on all interfaces');
```